# What did I do wrong here? The only error I get is near the bottom. Use of unassigned local variable 'parts' right after "add tax"

Tags: c#, unassigned-variable

```
 private decimal TaxCharges()
    {
        decimal addTax;
        decimal parts;

        addTax = parts * 0.06m;
        taxTxtBx.Text = addTax.ToString("c");
        return addTax;
    }
```

unassigned local variable 'parts' right after "addTax = parts

Comment: You haven't given parts a value, eg parts = 0

Comment: what a terrible title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `parts` has never been assigned a value.

Assign it a value before making use of the variable. For example:

```
decimal parts = 0;
```

Comment: That is great. Please accept an answer so that it now shows as a question with an answer (gets it off the unanswered lists).

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign values to the variables in order to initialize them.

E.g.

```
decimal addTax = 0;
```

The same with parts needs a value.

Good luck.